# Has there recently been a trending popularity with scissors as weapons over swords?

Tags: tropes, culture

Why are scissors starting to displace swords as the cool weapon of choice for main heroines to wield? (*Inu to Hasami wa Tsukaiyou*, *Kill la Kill*)

Comment: I don't think your premise is true. Two shows do not a trend make.

Comment: @senshin There are other recent examples of scissors (c.f. [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kNPQd.jpg)). I'm not sure this is an answerable question, but there does seem to be some sort of trend.

Comment: @LoganM You can't really count Souseiseki in the trend as she has sheers to compliment Suiseiseki watering pale which fits their natures as dream gardeners, and Rozen Maiden isn't actually recent as it's been around since 2002, it's just that a forth season is recent

Comment: Swords and knives as weapons are getting boring, guns are normally illegal, so that leaves scissors (and staplers).

Comment: I'll throw in the scissors from Guilty Crown too.

Comment: The recent trending of Kuchisake onna due to the movie of last year (2012: Kuchisake-onna Returns) might also have its effects.

Comment: And, at least eponymously, Pumpkin Scissors.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily a trend, perhaps, but it's worth noting that there's more than enough anime with swords (http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/KatanasAreJustBetter), even guns, that when a unique, less-frequent choice of weaponry comes around, it may catch the attention of a frequent anime viewer.

Example: Would Bakemonogatari episode 1 would have been more interesting if Senjougahara used a sword instead of a stapler? *Probably* not, unless you had some philia regarding swords.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

It is part of the clothes theme in Kill la Kill (even the school building is a school uniform!). So the scissors alone are not following some trend.